# Let this functions form a group?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, functions

Let A be a set. Injective functions, surjective, by bijective
A to A form a group? I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: Well, in order to form a group, you should need a group operation. Is it composition, addition, derivation...? Then, what is the definition of a group? Can you prove that your set of functions form (or don't form) a group?

Comment: The text doesn't specify

Comment: The group operation is composition of functions of course, domain and range are $A$.

Comment: The text may not specify, but your imagination may suffice. Consider functions from the set $A$ to itself. What kind of binary operation on that set can you imagine?